# Laravel 5.4 - how to store playlists in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I just can't find the right way to store playlists in the database.

1. There is a model **Player** that hasMany **Playlist**
2. **Playlist** hasMany **Track**
3. It should be possible to change the order of tracks in the playlist
4. The tracks should be displayed using the paginate()
   method

What will be the best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by best practice. You've just describe how the entities will relate to each other and what it needs to do. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I just don't know how to do an ordering for tracks... User must have an opportunity to change ordering of tracks... I should create a table with `playlist_id`, `track_id`, `ordering` fields, or what?

Comment: You could just add an `order_by` column on the tracks table.

Comment: I can't because every playlist should have own ordering

Comment: Then `hasMany` wouldn't be the correct relationship. It should be a `belongsToMany`. Add the order column on the pivot table

Comment: I doesn't used pivots before, how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You should define [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship. And you can create a column named `order_value` or other column name to change the order.

```
$player->playlist->track->order_value = '13';
```